# three.js: transforming coordinates from camera space to scene space

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to place a cube relative to the camera, rather than relative to the scene. The thing is, to place it in the scene (which I have to do make it show), I have to know the scene coordinates that correspond to the cubes camera space coordinates. I found this function "projectionMatrixInverse" in THREE.Camera. It has a nice function called "multiplyVector3" which I hoped would enable me to transform a vector (1,1,1) back to scene space like this:

```
var camera, myvec, multvec; // (and others)
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( window.innerWidth / - 2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / - 2, - 2000, 1000 );
camera.position.x = 200;
camera.position.y = 100;
camera.position.z = 200;

myvec = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1);
console.log("myvec: ", myvec);
multvec = camera.projectionMatrixInverse.multiplyVector3(THREE.Vector3(1,1,1));
console.log("multvec: ", multvec);
```

the thing is, on the console i get:

```
myvec: Object { x=1, y=1, z=1}
TypeError: v is undefined
var vx = v.x, vy = v.y, vz = v.z;
```

multiplyVector3 simply doesn't accept my `myvec`, or says it's undefined, even though the console says it's an object. I don't get it.

Comment: You want to add a box in front of the camera?

Comment: Yes. The point is to move a semi transparent brick around, following the camera. When the user has found the place he wants the brick to be, he left clicks, and the brick gets added too that spot In the scene space. A bit like minecraft actually, except in minecraft you don't see the brick you're about to add/destroy. I'll let the scroll wheel determine the bricks position in the front/back axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may also be what you're after:

```
scene.add( camera );

brick.position.set( 0, 0, -1 );
camera.add( brick );
```

Comment: It sure works. A cube is put in front of the camera. I'm just puzzled that changing the z value does not change the cubes position. I can even make it positive, and it's still in its usual spot in front of the camera.

Comment: Uh, that's strange. If you have it at, say, `0, 0, 200` is still in front of the camera?

Comment: Yep. Have a look at line 212 in this file:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2070405/webgl_geometry_cube_new.js

If you want to see it live, go here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2070405/webgl_geometry_cube_new.html

Comment: Oh. You're using `OrthographicCamera`. There is no depth when using `OrthographicCamera`.

Answer (score 4):

The camera is located at the origin of it's coordinate system, and looks down it's negative-Z axis. A point directly in front of the camera has camera coordinates of the form `( 0, 0, z )`, where `z` is a negative number.

You convert a point `p`

```
p = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once and reuse if you can

p.set( x, y, z );
```

from camera coordinates to world coordinates like so:

```
p.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );
```

`camera.matrixWorld` is by default updated every frame, but if need be, you can update it yourself by calling `camera.updateMatrixWorld();`

three.js r.95